# Let $T: R_3 \to R_2$ be the transformation defined by $T(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ = $(4x_1, x_1x_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I was working through this problem and I am having trouble because I am going from $R_3 \to R_2$. I guess that part is throwing me off. Can anyone help me understand how the steps change depending on this factor? I am trying to see if this is a linear transformation. I think I am just letting it confuse me.

Comment: What does it mean to be linear?

Comment: Arranged on or by a straight line?

Comment: What it means to be linear is that $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$ and $T(\lambda x) =\lambda T(x)$ for any scalar $\lambda$

Comment: how sorry yes that is the rule for being a linear transformation. But what was throwing me off was:

Comment: So in this problem do I just ignore the $x_3$?

Comment: while looking for T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v) I got $a_1 + b_1$ * $a_2+b_2$ compared to $a_1 + b_1$ + $a_2+b_2$. So that makes it non linear already right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, write $x=ax_1+bx_2+cx_3$ and $y=dx_1+ex_2+fx_3$. Then $T(x)=T(ax_1,bx_2,cx_3)= (4ax_1, ax_1bx_2)$. and  $T(y)=T(dx_1,ex_2,fx_3)= (4dx_1, dx_1ex_2)$. Similarly, you can compute $T(x+y)$, is this equal to $T(x)+T(y)=(4ax_1, ax_1bx_2)+(4cx_1, cx_1dx_2)$?

Repeat this for $\lambda T(x)$ and $T(\lambda x)$ and ask "are these two also equal"? If the answer to both questions is yes, then the transformation is linear.

In some sense $x_3$ is being ignored, but you must deal with any arbitrary vector of the form $x=ax_1+bx_2+cx_3$, so in that sense you can't simply ignore it.

Comment: So when I did this I got that it is not a linear transformation am I right to conclude that?

Comment: Yes, notice that $(2,2,0) \mapsto (8,4)$ but $2(2,2,0)=(4,4,0) \mapsto (16,16) \neq 2(8,4)$

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense. Thank you for the help. I think the $x_3$ just thew mw off a bit but especially when you format it like that, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: No problem, it may seem strange at first, but if you look at every addition that happens, it happens with vectors that are compatible. For example in $x+y$, you're adding 3-d vectors, which are compatible, whereas with $T(x)+T(y)$ you are adding 2-d vectors, which are compatible. Then $T(x+y)$ is then a 2-d vector, so it is valid to ask if it equal to the 2-d vector $T(x) +T(y)$